# Cordova linkedin login (SocialGap)

Tags: cordova, linkedin-api, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to integrate https://github.com/YanchWare/SocialGap for linkedin login but i am confused with few required parameters.

```
 SocialGap.Linkedin_ChangeSettings('apiKey', 'secretKey', 'ldAppDomain', 'ldScopes');
```

Can someone provide me with an example for ldAppDomain and ldScopes.
Also what should be "Authorized Redirect URLs" in linkedin developer app? This is an android app so how can there be a redirect url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got it.
Hosted an empty php file on some temp server and gave that link in Twitter redirecturl as well as Social gap settings.
 When the twitter redirects to the provided link then this plugin itself listens to that an redirects it back to our app with response.